# Is it possible in Google Play why an App is not compatible with a device?

Tags: unity-game-engine, permissions, google-play, google-cardboard

Within the *AndroidManifest.xml* I can see the following lines:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So I guess the compatibility issue is due to some of the followings:

- minSdkVersion
- accelerometer
- gyroscope

Is it possible to know which one/s is the compatibility issue within Google Play. Should we check one by one "manually"?

Answer (score 0):

According with the answer of Google, it seems that nowadays we have to check it manually as I have stated in the question.

The answer of Google was: "If you'd like to know why specific device is not compatible with the app, you'll need to check if all the features you requested in the APK are supported by the device. Also you'll need to check the Android version"